# How do you get Ember Data to recognize that the server is returning IDs for hasMany relationships?

Tags: json, ember.js, ember-data

My server returns JSON responses that look like this:

```
{
  'book': {
    'id': 252,
    'name': 'The Hobbit',
    'tag_ids': [1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7]
   }
}
```

I'm using Ember Data's `DS.RESTSerializer`, which I've extended to include a `keyForRelationship` function that recognizes that keys ending in `"_ids"` are really hasMany relationships. Thus, the above code should match up just fine with my model code, which looks like this:

```
App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    tags: DS.hasMany('tag')
});
```

The problem is that whenever I create a new book and the server returns its JSON response, Ember Data's store gets it wrong. It fails to convert the IDs into actual `tag` instances. Instead, the `tags` property on the model is literally set to an array of IDs.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried to define `tags` as async, like: `DS.hasMany('tag', {async: true})`

Comment: yep, tried that, no real success. looks like the correct answer was to use the new DS.ActiveModelAdapter instead of DS.RESTAdapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should consider using `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` instead of `DS.RESTAdapter`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/19209194/1345947